# Why is an Amazon device reporting as wired when it's connecting via WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

My home DSL router/modem has a very simple network 'map' which is basically just a list of devices wired/wireless.

I have a single ethernet cable to the back of the router, plugged into a small powered hub used to provide wired networking to my home office. So there is the hub, and my Mac plugged into that, and nothing else.
But I see two wired devices listed - my Mac, and amazon-kljlkij8kj or similar. I do have an Amazon Fire TV stick but it is on WiFi.

Why is the amazon device listed as wired when it isn't, and why is my hub *not* listed?

Comment: Hub is a passive device, it doesn't have any network identity. Can you share a screenshot of the list with context?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean switch and not hub. Hubs are layer-1 repeaters, switches are layer-2 intelligent switching devices. In either case, they will not show up under the network map. Most modems and routers only show you what layer-3(IP) devices it has seen through either arp, or DHCP addresses it has handed out.

Comment: Try updating the modem firmware, I have seen plenty of home-grade equipment mis-identify a interface some client device is connected to. It's usually just crappy firmware.

Answer (score -1):

Your "modem" (I assume you mean router) has no way of knowing HOW your Fire Stick is connected, it just sees that a device is connected based on its ARP table. Your "hub" (I assume you're referring to an unmanaged switch) does not have an IP or MAC address so your router does not see it.